# noexcept keyword is not supported by MSVC in 2016

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I am asking this question because I just can't believe that it is 2016 and MSVC compiler still does not support `noexcept` keyword. The following simple code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() noexcept
    {
    }
};
```

Generates this error:

```
error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier
```

This code compiles by Visual Studio on Win32 platform, but it generates this error when I am trying to compile it on UWP. Am I missing something obvious or are they using different C++ compilers for Win32 and UWP?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3. Version 14.0.25424.00.

Comment: Looks like it does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956976.aspx - check your compilation options

Comment: Like a fair few compilers, it may not compile as C++2011 by default.

Comment: @Peter I was not able to find any compiler option that would help, but It does feel like all c+11 features are disabled. Initializer lists, constexpr, etc. do not compile as well, but work fine when I compile the same project for Win32.

Comment: @Peter. Looks like I found what the problem is. For some reason my UWP projects are defaulted to using v12 (VS2013) platform toolset, which explains why most of c++ features are not supported. The other problem I am now trying to solve is that v12 toolset is the only available option and I cannot switch to v14.

Comment: Seems like this is a problem of using a free distribution - you're limited to whatever features the free version supports.

Comment: @Peter: That's a problem with _any_ distribution. Cost is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lightness - in this case, the OP is using a free version of a particular product, and seeking to use features that are in the paid version of that produce but not in the free version.  That is often a problem associated with using a free version of a product when a paid version of that product is available.   The reverse problem - a paid version of a vendor's product lacking features that are in a free version - is pretty rare in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using old Windows8.1 project files. The projects were configured to use old v12 platform toolset (Visual Studio 2013), which explains why C++11 features were unavailable. At the same time, there is no way to switch to use newer v14 toolset (VS2015) other than to create new Universal App project (not Windows8 universal).